# How can I set gradle project properties when using gradle tooling API?

Tags: gradle, groovy, gradle-tooling-api

I'm trying to use the tooling API to run a gradle task from groovy code.  The following works:

```
ProjectConnection connection = GradleConnector.newConnector()
            .forProjectDirectory(new File(System.properties.getProperty('user.dir')))
            .connect()    

connection.newBuild()
            .forTasks('deploy')
            .setStandardOutput(System.out)
            .run()
```

But the task I want to run depends on project properties.  For example, if I was running it from the command line, I'd use

```
 gradle -Penv=local deploy
```

I can't figure out how, using the tooling API, to set those project values.

Comment: Can't you add `.withArguments('-Penv=local')` before the `.forTasks` line?

Comment: Color me embarrassed.  I tried that, repeatedly, before posting, but was unsuccessful because of a typo.  

After your comment, I went back and retyped the line and it suddenly started working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
connection.newBuild()
            .withArguments('-Penv=local')
            .forTasks('deploy')
            .setStandardOutput(System.out)
            .run()
```